# Amazon S3 bucket upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3, app-config

How can I change my amazon s3 bucket name depending on what development area I am on.

For example: for testing and Development I have same amazon s3 bucket. But I want to change the bucket names dynamically depending on the environment the application will be.

I have something like this now:

```
$this->s3->putObjectFile($thumb_config['new_image'], 'newimage',
                                         $filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

I want this newimage to be dynamic depending on which server the application will be.

I can make this newimage as a variable but then how I set values to this variable.

Please share your ideas, thoughts and experience with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an environment configuration file: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html#environments

You would create this file in:

`./application/config/{ENVIRONMENT}/{FILENAME}.php`

CodeIgniter will first try to load a configuration file from the current environment - if none is found, it will look for a global configuration file.

For example:

`./application/config/production/aws.php`

`./application/config/development/aws.php`

Locally, the development configuration will be loaded, but on a production server with the environment set to production - an alternative config can be provided.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks I think this is a good solution. I have a question now, if I say something like this: $filename = devfilename in the development aws.php  and $filename = profilename in the production aws.php how I use it in my controllers code. I mean do I have to call it or it will load automatically where it will see $filename according to the environment it is on. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Within your controller, you would load the config:
`$this->config->load('aws', TRUE);`

You can then access the bucket name, depending upon your configuration file, like:
`$bucket = $this->config->item('bucket', 'aws');`

Comment: Alternatively, you could return the full AWS config and access it as an array:

`$aws = $this->config->item('aws');`
`$bucket = $aws['bucket'];`